# How to get full timestamp value from dataframes? values being truncated

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sql-timestamp

I have a function "toDate(v:String):Timestamp" that takes a string an converts it into a timestamp with the format "MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.NS".

I make a udf of the function:

```
val u_to_date = sqlContext.udf.register("u_to_date", toDate_)
```

The issue happens when you apply the UDF to `dataframes`. The resulting `dataframe` will lose the last 3 nanoseconds.
For example when using the argument "0001-01-01 00:00:00.123456789"
The resulting dataframe will be in the format
[0001-01-01 00:00:00.123456]

I have even tried a dummy function that returns `Timestamp.valueOf("1234-01-01 00:00:00.123456789")`. When applying the `udf` of the dummy function, it will truncate the last 3 nanoseconds.

I have looked into the sqlContext conf and
spark.sql.parquet.int96AsTimestamp is set to True. (I tried when it's set to false)

I am at lost here. What is causing the truncation of the last 3 digits?

---

example

The function could be:
 `def date123(v: String): Timestamp = {
     Timestamp.valueOf("0001-01-01 00:00:00.123456789")
  }`
It's just a dummy function that should return a timestamp with full nanosecond precision.

Then I would make a udf:

```
`val u_date123 = sqlContext.udf.register("u_date123", date123 _)`
```

example df:

`val theRow =Row("blah")
val theRdd = sc.makeRDD(Array(theRow))
case class X(x: String )
val df = theRdd.map{case Row(s0) => X(s0.asInstanceOf[String])}.toDF()`

If I apply the udf to the dataframe `df` with a string column, it will return a dataframe that looks like '[0001-01-01 00:00:00.123456]'

`df.select(u_date123($"x")).collect.foreach(println)`

Comment: Well... where is your `toDate` function ?

Comment: To be clear @SarveshKumarSingh asked for a [mcve].

Comment: I dont think the function matters. I think the issue might be a spark limitation or bug. I have added example in the original post

Comment: Actually it does matter. What if your function is somewhere using a time representation which is limited to miliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the issue.

On spark 1.5.1, they changed the size of the timestamp datatype from 12 bytes to 8 bytes

https://fossies.org/diffs/spark/1.4.1_vs_1.5.0/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/types/TimestampType.scala-diff.html

I tested on spark 1.4.1, and it produces the full nanosecond precision.

Comment: did you find any workaround to support nano second precision?